# Listbuilder in separate widget not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I tried the listbuilder demo from Flutter.io. That works great, however I would like to add the page a textview, so I moved the listbuilder into a separate Widget, that throws the following error:

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out. The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderStack#894cd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT Unfortunately, this object's geometry is not known at this time, probably because it has never been laid out. This means it cannot be accurately hit-tested. If you are trying to perform a hit test during the layout phase itself, make sure you only hit test nodes that have completed layout (e.g. the node's children, after their layout() method has been called).)

The full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(
    items: List<String>.generate(10, (i) => "Item $i"),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: body(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget body() {
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('${items[index]}'),
          );
        },
      )
    ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove the `Column` in `body()`:

```dart
  Widget body() {
    return Container(
        child: /* Column(children: <Widget>[ */
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('${items[index]}'),
          );
        },
      )
    /* ]) */);
  }
```

It is because the `Column` seems have no specific size to render children widgets.
More info: https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints#flex

---

update @ 2019.02.18:

To add siblings for the List, you can try wrapping it with `Expanded`, and then add the siblings.

```dart
  Widget body() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text('DropdownButton'),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${items[index]}'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ])
    ),
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!

That works, but I would like to place a DropdownButton above the List (listbuilder) to select Database table to list items.

That is why I was thinking in colums. What could I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ListView in Flexible

```
Widget body() {
return Container(
    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text('${items[index]}'),
      );
    },
  )
)

]));
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt I honestly don't know why wrapping in Flexible will make this work as the error is weird for me (HitTest). But I just assumed it has something to do with height constraints being unbounded. Flexible is just like Expanded but has its flexf fit set to loose insted of tight in Exapnded widgets.